# should I use the `expect` statement within loop on Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

Currently I'm testing an app with Jest and Enzyme, that sometimes requires to validate if there is a tag present or not on some components, this is a situation that is repeated in most of the modules.

I was thinking to create an util that receives all of the selectors, for example `['.headline', '.foo', '.bar']` then iterate the array to to validate if they exists or not.

Having that said, is a good approach? shouldn't I test in that way?, what would you do in this case to avoid code repetition?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with using a loop to replace what you would have to write down manually otherwise as an enormous list of statements. I do it in my tests without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

My general suggestions:

- Make sure your automatic tests are independent.
- Making expectations about the code explicit in your test code means it will be easy for others to understand its expected behavior, and to change it when requirements change.

Regarding your questions regarding an utility. It could make sense if it make the code easy to understand and avoid in a simple way some repetition. Just make sure it is simple as possible and do one task only.